# Library for minimum bounding box "by width" in JavaScript or Python

Tags: python, javascript, algorithm, extents, library

I'm looking for a library (or at least a code snippet) to calculate the minimum bounding box "by width" in JavaScript or Python. Below is an illustration from the ArcGIS documentation of that functionality. Ideally the function would give me also the angle, width and height of the bounding box. Any pointers?

[image]

Image courtesy of the [ArcGIS documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000)

Comment: OpenCV has a module of that sort http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect

Comment: Thanks for the OpenCV pointer but I believe this function does a "Rectangle by Area" and not a "by width" approach.

Comment: Is this what you tried to achieve in JS/Python? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/260488/122597

Comment: Check out http://turfjs.org bbox and envelope modules, maybe they fit your needs.

Comment: QGIS has a "Minimum bounding geometry" tool that do exactly that (and a few of the other possibilities) you may have a look at the algorithm it use (it seem to be using python)

Comment: @J.R: No, that tool does not include this specific "by width" algorithm.

Comment: @BenediktGroß you're right this tool is "by area" not "by width" but this discussion about the tool : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/5111 says it "should be trivial to add" the "by width" option to match the ESRI tool, maybe you could try to look at that