# Creating “oblique bounding box” with maximum width/height ratio in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents

In QGIS I would like to create bounding boxes that align with the polygon footprint.

When using "Oriented minimum bounding box" it skews the bounding possibly based on the world aligned positions. 
[image: Oriented minimum bounding box result]

When using "Bounding Boxes" it has a similar issue using a true min max position. 
[image: Bounding Boxes result]

The desired result I am after would be this:
[image: desired result]

There is a similar question already posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260558). It offers a script that seems to have a good answer. I would like to know how to achieve the same thing in QGIS. I have tried to find an equivalent of `ST_Rotate` etc but have not found anything specific.

Comment: Are your data in the same CRS than your project? If not, re-project the data into the system that you want to have for the result and set the project to use the same CRS.

Comment: @user30184Yes they are. But it's like the bounding box stuff always aligns with the north.

Comment: Even the oriented ones?

Comment: I think you may be correct, I am starting to think that I have my shape layers the same CRS, but the projects is different. I am also getting skewing on polys when I do a rotation. Thanks, heaps I will investigate further.